# iTextSharp - Extracting PDF NOOP (%%) Comments

Tags: pdf, itext

Are these available to the the Itext/iTextSharp library?

I can see them directly when opening in a Text editor.

```
%%ADVICE_DATE: 31 March 2015
%%COUNT_OF_EMAILS: 0
%%CLIENT_ID: 128372
%%PRODUCT_CODE: JJE
%%PAGE_COUNT_FOR_CUST: 2
%%CUSTOMER_END: CUSTOMER_END
%%CUSTOMER_START: CUSTOMER_START
```

But is there anyway of pulling this information from each page without reading the PDF file as text.  As ideally I'd like the page this was found on.

These aren't annotations.

Comment: As far as I know itext ignores such comments when parsing the file. If that indeed is the case, you either have to change the parser to somehow process them or parse the pdf separately for those comments.

Comment: *But is there anyway of pulling this information from each page* - where exactly are those comments? I ask because only a few pdf objects are clearly associated with a single page. Thus, depending on the exact location of the comment there might be no page to which it is canonically associated.